# Quantum mechanics basic postulates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, wavefunction, observables

let me change the question. consider a wave function.
$$\varphi(x)$$
It is considered as a good wave function if  it satisfies the following conditions.

1. it is a function meaning it is defined for all the input values of x
2. it is a smooth function meaning it is infinitely differentiable
3. it is normalizable means that  $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{|\varphi|}^2dx$$ exists
4. its fourier transform is a function such that its mod square is integrate able over all momentum range. and also is normalizable and it normalizes to the same value as the $\varphi(x)$

now I think that these conditions are the things that define the wave function space.

And I know that a physical quantum state is actually a complex plane passing through the origin in the above defined state space of wave function which also happens to be a complex vector space.

so I have a question now consider any arbitrary function $f(x,p)$ where x is position and p in momentum. and $f$ is such that  it emits a same physical dimension real value  for all $(x,p)$ set. so we can say that a $f(x,p)$ is a physical observable with its own physical dimension.

so for a physical state can we get all the valid PDFs for the suspected observables?
like for physical observable.

1. $$f(x,p)=(\alpha p^2+\beta x^2)^{1/2}$$
2. or $$=(|xp|+\beta p^2)^{1/2}$$
3. or some random function with some random dimension

If we can, then what will be the respective linear Hermitian operator for them. this is the part one of the question.  and I am not even asking about the multivariable PDFs because it requires the knowledge of the commutation of the physical observables.

now for part 2 of the question since we have defined the state space with the above condition  when we take space of linear Hermitian operators on them now do they give back the same state space but with a different physical dimension.
Like for example if we take position operator whose domain is the above defined state space.
then we can write .
$$\hat{x}\varphi(x)=x\varphi(x)$$
so do the resulting state also satisfy the above conditions . does this happen for all the operators. because if it doesn't then how can we even multiply the  operators because if the in $AB$ operator if B gives out some function that doesn't satisfy the above properties then how can A take that as an input.

And also aren't these operators supposed to be defined for all the elements of the above space. like when I was reading about the hydrogen atom quantum mechanics it had like $1/x$ as potential energy operator. but isn't that operator undefined as it outputs undefined functions for many input functions. or is the potential energy operator like this
$$\hat{potential}\varphi(x)=\begin{cases} 
  \varphi(x)/x & x!=0 \\
  0 & x=0.
   \end{cases}$$
Or my third question would be that is all this sort of definition of state space of wave functions and operators somewhat primitive and we need some kind of Hilbert space like definition to it and the operators linearly transform that space ,which includes the momentum observable and position observable and all the possible observables.

Comment: "And I know that a physical quantum state is actually a complex plane passing through the origin in the above defined state space of wave function" ...why, what do you mean?

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html

Comment: the conditions mentioned here are the easiest to understand. in this link. thankyou didn't know that the constraints included the Schrodinger equation . this clarifies the undefined ness of the Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is considered as a good wave function if it satisfies the following conditions.
>
> 2. it is a smooth function meaning it is infinitely differentiable
>
> now I think that these conditions are the things that define the wave function space.

Why are you trying to do this? Also, we know from general principles that the actual electron density functions that properly solve the quantum physics problems, will have a cusp at the nuclei that contain the information of the charge of the nuclei, see Kato's theorem. This means that the wavefunction will be weird at the nuclei. I really do not think that trying to postulate quantum theory from an approach like yours will be fruitful, given the much better postulates of quantum theory that we currently have.

> And I know that a physical quantum state is actually a complex plane passing through the origin in the above defined state space of wave function which also happens to be a complex vector space.

I am joined by others in being unable to understand what you might be trying to mean here. It definitely does not even sound correct.

> consider any arbitrary function $f(x,p)$ where $x$ is position and $p$ is momentum. and $f$ is such that it emits a same physical dimension real value for all $(x,p)$ set. so we can say that a $f(x,p)$ is a physical observable with its own physical dimension.

What do you mean by ``physical dimension"? What is "physical dimension real value"?

> so for a physical state can we get all the valid PDFs for the suspected observables? like for physical observable.

Your problem statement is too unclear for us to give a definitive statement either way. We do have some theorems to guarantee validity for certain classes, and also counterexamples for cases where they fail. You have to be much more precise to be able to talk about this topic.

> 3. or some random function with some random dimension

What do you mean by ``dimension"?

> Like, for example, if we take position operator whose domain is the above defined state space, then we can write
> $$\hat x\varphi(x)=x\varphi(x)$$
> so do the resulting state also satisfy the above conditions?

They do not. Take, for example, the plane wave $\varphi=e^{ikx}$, and it is exceedingly clear that the equation you stated is still supposed to be correct, but there is no way to normalise this. In general, there are plenty of situations whereby the wavefunctions might still be normalisable, but after action of an operator, the resulting thing is not normalisable. There is really nothing particularly physically interesting about this behaviour; you will just get used to this after a while of familiarity with the subject.

> And also aren't these operators supposed to be defined for all the elements of the above space. like when I was reading about the hydrogen atom quantum mechanics it had like $1/x$ as potential energy operator. but isn't that operator undefined as it outputs undefined functions for many input functions.

This is a good question. You have really kind of answered your own question above: The Hamiltonian operator $\hat{\mathcal H}$ is one of those $f(x,p)$ that you have mentioned earlier. The fact that $\hat V(\vec{\hat r})\propto1/r$ is singular at the origin just means that $\hat V$ alone is nonsense. Instead, the Hamiltonian operator $\hat{\mathcal H}=\frac1{2m}\hat p^2+\hat V$ is *together* meaningful, and able to have $\hat{\mathcal H}\psi=E\psi$, including in the neighbourhood of the origin, where each individual part alone has diverged.

> Or my third question would be that is all this sort of definition of state space of wave functions and operators somewhat primitive and we need some kind of Hilbert space like definition to it and the operators linearly transform that space ,which includes the momentum observable and position observable and all the possible observables.

It should be kind of clear from this question-and-answer that, yes, please follow standard presentations of quantum theory. The geniuses who put them together have already thought through most of the kind of questions that you might be asking.

Comment: a physical state is given by a non trivial wave function . now if we multiply that wave function with any complex number we still get a point in the state space  but it will have the same properties so I think that set of all the states that we get by scaling the wave function by complex value all represents the same physical state.

and by physical dimension I mean just the measuring units that is if the $f$ is emitting a length or length squared and obviously it will give a real value.

Comment: Also the conditions that I wrote obviously comes from the absolute basics, were I have read that those conditions have to be satisfied. But obviously I don't think that's the case anymore by your answer and the defining conditions are totally different

Comment: and the last part of your answer, like yeah I get it, the Hamiltonian , but even it is undefined because it has $1/r$ in it still. but it is undefined for the conditions that I wrote . SO I have no Idea on the mathematical consistency of this thing but still I think that there is a consistent way  of doing it and that's kind what I am asking but in a very basic way.

Comment: About the multiplication by complex number and still getting the same quantum state, the name for it is that physical states are rays in the Hilbert space. It is definitely not a 2D thing. If by physical dimension you mean units, then you need to know that, although we do talk about the dimensions of units, the way you are using it is just wrong, and not ever used by professionals. As for the 1/r, as I said, the singularity in 1/r has to be cancelled out by the Laplacian term, so that the finite eigenvalues are possible. There is no physical singularity left after that.